# Setting the height of a SELECT in IE without font-size

Tags: css, select

IE7 seems to ignore the height set in CSS when rendering a HTML SELECT. Are there any work around's for this? I want to increase height of the select without increasing the font on IE7.

Comment: check out this alternate approach http://lilianagaete.com/blog/make-the-dropdown-work-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `line-height:` CSS property